# How to read excel file java..?

Tags: java, jsp

My Question is I want to read Excel file using browse button in `(html or JSP)`, then I want to display the records of Excel sheet on Web Page `(JSP)`.

Comment: Please this I want...I am new here.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: download JXL/Apache POI  JAR(I personally prefer JXL). Look up some basic tutorials on HTML/JSP and JXL/POI then, come back here with your errors/problems (i am being optimistic here :P)

Comment: Then please go though the information on the 'help' link on the upper right, to see why this will probably be closed in its current form.

Comment: I downloaded all POI api..and putted in library folder of NETBeans.

Comment: @SachinKumar - So, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `POI` jar from Apache, by using that you can get your excel sheet data. then you  can do what ever you want.

You can [find Jar file at here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpoi37beta1jar.htm).

**Example code:**

```
    String filename = request.getParameter("file");

    String str = "/file path";

        fis = new FileInputStream(str);

        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<?> rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        LinkedList<String> llstr=new LinkedList<String>();

        while (rows.hasNext())
        {
            HSSFRow rowno = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
            int i = rowno.getRowNum();

            Iterator<?> cells = rowno.cellIterator();

            while (cells.hasNext())
            {

                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();

                if (i != 0 && i != 1)
                {
                    int type = cell.getCellType();

                    if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                    {

                        llstr.add(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());

                    }
                    else if (type == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                    {

                        String s = Integer.toString((int) cell
                                .getNumericCellValue());

                        llstr.add(s);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        Iterator<String> it=llstr.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {

        }
```

This is usually used to retrieve data from excel sheet.

For more information, have a look at [Reading/writing excel files in java : POI tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/).
 Hope this will help you.